# Why did the Centre keep Jarod inside a bubble?

Tags: the-pretender

In the American action drama, sci-fi TV series *The Pretender* (1996-2000), Jarod, the pretender, a child prodigy stolen from his parents when he was 4 years old, is kept isolated inside the Centre, a sinister think tank located in the fictional Blue Cove, Delaware, who exploited his Pretender abilities. As a part of their research, the Centre presents to Jarod a large number of complexes 'sims'; simulated hypothetical situations designed to exploit the young genius' intellect for real life nefarious purposes.

During the entry credits of each episode, it can be seen a black and white scene -very briefly- with Jarod laying inside a bubble or a transparent sphere with Sidney, Jarod's mentor and coach, walking around.

Along the series, there are few flashbacks where Jarod together with the bubble recur. I have watched most of the episodes, but I haven't been able to know why the Centre kept Jarod inside a bubble. Was that part of a simulation?

By the way, there is a track from the original score of the TV show entitled "In the bubble" by Velton Ray but the lyrics doesn't appear to be related to Jarod and the bubble.

[image: Still image of The Pretender]

Comment: Rule of cool would be my guess and to show how isolated they kept him.

Comment: @Paulie_D - I really believe the flashback scene exist but it can be easily missed in the twinkling of an eye in any of those 86 episodes.

Comment: FWIW, he's shown in the bubble during the second episode, but I don't think it expands on why.

Comment: A wild guess would suggest that is to keep him focused: he can't move (yet he is not restrained), there are no other stimuli. It looks like a bit like a sensory deprivation chamber with only his "minder" as a source of data to external world

Comment: @Yasskier - Thats an interesting POV but it could be, also, just the contrary. There is a flashback scene (S01E14) with Jarod in the sphere (I think) during a simulation called Apollo One, where tongues of fire surround him while suffering from apparent extreme temperatures. I mean, the pod could serve as a mean to expose Jarod to whatever stimuli the Centre want.